# Can anyone give me the documentation of "Get started: write and deploy your first functions" with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-platform

There is this document from the Firebase about how to write and deploy the cloud function in Nodejs but can anyone help me out getting that very document in python. I am getting confused as I am a newbie in this field?

However, I tried to write my cloud function which looks like the below but constantly getting some errors that I am going to mention below:

```
import json
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
def go_firebase(request):
    cred = credentials.Certificate('firebasesdk.json')
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://firebaseio.com/'
    })
    ref=db.reference('agents')
    snapshot = ref.order_by_key().get()
    for key, val in snapshot.items():
        kw=val
        dictfilt = lambda x, y: dict([ (i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y) ])
        wanted_keys = ("address","name","phone","uid")
        result = dictfilt(kw, wanted_keys)
        data= json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True)
        return data
```

And after deploying the function with http trigger, in the log, it is saying:

```
severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 313, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 215, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 208, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 6, in go_firebase
    cred = credentials.Certificate('firebasesdk.json')
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 83, in __init__
    with open(cert) as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'firebasesdk.json'
```

I have no idea why it is saying file not found because I have that json file in the same path where I am executing the function! I am using google cloud shell!
Can anyone be kind enough to tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `cred = credentials.Certificate('/orbocare-dev-firebase-adminsdk-wm252-cd32dc9b9b.json')` is a different path than your error message implies. Note the `/` at the start of that path, it is an *absolute* path, expecting that file to live in the root of your file system.

Comment: Can you do a locate or a find on firebasesdk.json and than add the absolute path for this file to fetch credentials?

Comment: Hello @Martijn! So what should I do?

Comment: Hello @Raunak! I tried giving the absolute path but it still says the same thing filenotfound.

Comment: @DataDevourer: either use a relative path (but that requires you to always use the exact same current working directory), or use an absolute path. You can base your path off of `__file__` if you need to be able to move this project location around; see [How to properly determine current script directory?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3718657)

Comment: @DataDevourer: then your path is still incorrect. All that `firebase_admin.credentials.Credentials()` does with it is trying to open the path you give.

Comment: @Martijn, the path problem is solved now but now I am getting some other error saying:--  "TypeError: go_firebase() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: Here is the log: textPayload:  "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 313, in run_http_function
    result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 215, in invoke_user_function
    return call_user_function(request_or_event)

Comment: File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 208, in call_user_function
    return self._user_function(request_or_event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.json` file that you are referring to is probably the dependencies file for Node.js Cloud Function.

**How it works**

Every Google Cloud Function has an extra file (additionally to the main code) that has all the libraries to be installed. For example if you are using `requests` library in your code then there is no way of running `pip install requests` before executing the main code. Therefore you add this library in the additional file and the Cloud Function will first read that file during deployment and will try to install all the libraries mentioned there.

For Node.js code the file with the libraries is a `.json` file. For the `Python` it is a `requirements.txt` file. For more information, you can refer to [The Python Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime) documentation.